# ajax php javascript : error when using POST method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I searched on google, and there are so much question about this topic on stackoverflow. Such as 'data not being sent on post method', etc.
But seem not asnwer my question

The case is almost the same with other questions. These are the error msg:

Firefox (v21) :

```
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Chrome (v27) :

```
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
```

When the request is sent by `GET`, there is no error. And all GET data received well.

But when sent by `POST` + `setRequestHeader`, itu occurs error like above. When `setRequestHeader` removed, the error is gone. No error, but the POST data is not received. i `print_r($_POST)`; then the array is empty

Question Updated. Here is the caller:

```
goServer({
    url     : 'users/sign-in.php',
    method  : 'POST',
    data    : 'randomId=' + randomId + '&name=' + name + '&password=' + password,
    done    : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    fail    : function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

And here is the functions (sorry, long lines ):

```
function randomString() {
    var str = new Date().getTime(),
    str2    = Math.random();

    str     = str.toString();
    str2    = str2.toString();
    str2    = str2.substring(2,7);
    str     += str2;

    return str;
}



function goServer(opts) {
    var xhr    = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = requestComplete;

    function requestComplete() {
        if ( xhr.readyState === 4 ) {
            if ( xhr.status === 200 ) {
                opts.done(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                opts.fail(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
    }

    if ( !opts.method || opts.method === undefined ) {
        opts.method    = "GET";
    }

    if ( !opts.cache || opts.cache === undefined ) {
        opts.cache    = false;
    }

    if ( opts.cache === false ) {
        opts.url    += '?nocache=' + randomString();
    } else {
        opts.url    += '?nocache=false';
    }

    if ( opts.method === "GET" ) {
        if ( opts.data !== '' && opts.data !== undefined ) {
            opts.url    += '&' + opts.data;
        }
        opts.data    = '';
    } else {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }

    xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url, true);
    xhr.send(opts.data);

}
```

Note, the data parameter (opts.data) is set to the url when it sent by GET. When sent by POST, the paramater is set to the xhr.send(opts.data);

Question : How to get the POST data correctly?

Thank you

Comment: post the code too please

Comment: `print_r(file_get_contents('php://input'));` < Your POST data here. But it not solves an issue. Post code please.

Comment: @CORRUPT , question updated :)

Comment: @DevZer0 , question was updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` after you call `xhr.open`

Also `opts.data` should be a string containing key/value pairs. e.g. `key=value&method=post`

Comment: Whoaaa, you are true Sir! You are true, yes, problem solved. Thank you so much

Comment: As you said, call `setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` after `xhr.open` and it works! Again, thank you very much, sir!